# Creating another window for just displaying text + swing

Tags: java, swing

I currently have a window frame with panels inside and am using it to run my program. Now I am in a need to display text along with running of the code side by side.

The problem with displaying it in the same window is that it minimizes the total screen area which I am using for input handling.

Thus I decided to create a dialog box and dump all the text inside.

This proved to be a bad decision as sometimes the output is really large and dialog boxes do not contain the scroll bar.

Can anyone tell me what's the best way to proceed?

I just want suggestions to what should I try and do not need any code part for it as I would like to do that on my own :)

Comment: @userNNNN "..dialog ..the output is really large and dialog boxes do not contain the scroll bar..."  They do if you put one inside them!  Note that a JSplitPane, JTabbedPane, CardLayout or JDesktopPane/JInternalFrame are all ways of providing more than one large component within a single JFrame.  Perhaps you should look into them before pursuing the current strategy.

Comment: Yes absolutely ... infact I gave up on the strategy that I said... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Create a new JWindow (or JFrame, one tutorial here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html)
- Inside of it, create a new JTextArea and dump all your text there
- to get the scrolling, create a new JScrollPane around your JTextArea. Tutorial: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html

Comment: Hey as I want to display both of the windows when I try to create a frame it says that cannot do so from within one container ... so can I do that ?

Comment: You can definitely create multiple windows. Not seeing your code I'm not sure what the issue you're seeing is about. try something like this: f = new JFrame(); f.setVisible(true)

Answer (score 1):

You should follow tradition and use either:

- One `JFrame` that will host your application and open any number of `JDialog`s your for your scrolling text etc.

or

- One `JFrame` with any number of `JInternalPane`s.

`JFrame` is a **top-level container** and every application should have only one. You do not loose any functionality this way, and you stick with the standards, which will definitely make somebody's life easier in the future. Maybe your's.